# flattr REST API v2 tutorials and examples

Tags: jquery-plugins, javascript

I am working in JqueryMobile, HTML-5.Today  I deeply search for `flattr REST API v2` this is very great API .  I  am trying to implement this API on my app right now i am following `http://developers.flattr.net/api/` .Is their  any .js lib exist for flattr REST API (and any flattr REST API tutorials link or videos) so do this work more comfortable. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one js plugin `https://github.com/simme/flattrjs/blob/master/flattr.js`
if any body have best and better information then please answer .